# How to make autoconf conditionally use system extensions?

Tags: c, autoconf

I'm trying to write a program that can use custom `stdio` streams on both Linux/glibc and FreeBSD, and to that end, I'm trying to write an autoconf script that can properly detect these and turn on the necessary compiler flags to support them.

On glibc, I need to define `_GNU_SOURCE` in order to gain access to `fopencookie` and `cookie_io_functions_t`. Autoconf neatly supports turning this on with `AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS`, but I can't quite seem to figure out how to only do this when necessary. Currently, I'm trying to do it like this:

```
HAS_FOPENCOOKIE=yes
AC_CHECK_FUNC(fopencookie, [AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS], [HAS_FOPENCOOKIE=no])
AC_CHECK_MEMBER([cookie_io_functions_t.read], [], [HAS_FOPENCOOKIE=no])
```

This *works*, per se, but autoconf complains loudly when I try to generate the configure script, several times, that `AC_COMPILE_IFELSE was called before AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS`. Apparently, it thinks it is really bad practice to actually do any tests before turning on system extensions.

What should I do about this? Just ignore the warnings? Do the necessary `AC_DEFINE` manually instead? (This latter seems ugly, since I'd need to define an `AH_TEMPLATE` as well and all that.) Just turn on all extensions that I may or may not use, unconditionally at the top of the file? Something completely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spoke with the good people on the Autoconf mailing list about this. Their opinion seems to be that since I'm not trying to be strictly compatible with something like POSIX or ANSI C, I should pretty much be using `AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS` anyway; and, that there should be no harm in doing so since I'm actually using a system extension, regardless of whether that extension actually is part of the default compilation environment or not.

I'll admit I'm not sure I fully understand the distinction between the default compilation environment and the "extended" one, but since that's their opinion about their own tool, I'll buy that and will let that be the authoritative answer.

Answer (score 3):

(Apologies in advance for the long answer, but I don't want to risk leaving too many details out.)

You should conditionally define `_GNU_SOURCE` using `AH_VERBATIM` to create a template and `AC_DEFINE` to define its value while leaving other systems' extensions disabled if you're wanting this done only for Glibc. Otherwise you're better off using the system extensions by default. See the first few lines of the code below for an example of what I have in mind with `AH_VERBATIM`.

You can leave out the if/else parts of your AC_CHECK_* calls and use shell code to test whether `$ac_cv_func_fopencookie` and `$ac_cv_member_cookie_io_functions_t_read` are both yes. If they're both yes, define `_GNU_SOURCE` to 1. Note that this has the potential to affect other tests with the compiler, so unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, you ought to perform this check and define `_GNU_SOURCE` before running any other compile tests (e.g. `AC_CHECK_FUNC`).

Note that in this case, it might be better to write your own test if you absolutely refuse to use system extensions. Unless I use `AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS`, or previously define `_GNU_SOURCE`, `cookie_io_functions_t` is an undefined type. Checking for that type will also require `_GNU_SOURCE`, and naturally once it is defined, you apparently cannot undefine it.

Here is an example of how I'd do it. It illustrates *why* you should use `AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS` since it only handles `_GNU_SOURCE`:

```
AC_DEFUN([ck_FUNC_FOPENCOOKIE],
[AH_VERBATIM(
    [_GNU_SOURCE],
    [/* Enable GNU extensions for fopencookie functionality to work
   where required. */
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#undef _GNU_SOURCE
#endif])

AC_CACHE_CHECK(
    [whether fopencookie works without _GNU_SOURCE being defined],
    [ck_cv_libc_fopencookie],
    [AC_LINK_IFELSE(
        [AC_LANG_SOURCE(
            [#undef _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>

cookie_read_function_t *ck_read = (cookie_read_function_t *)foo_read;
cookie_write_function_t *ck_write = (cookie_write_function_t *)ck_read;
cookie_seek_function_t *ck_seek = (cookie_seek_function_t *)ck_read;
cookie_close_function_t *ck_close = (cookie_close_function_t *)fclose;

size_t foo_read(void *cookie, char *buf, size_t size)
{
    cookie = buf;
    buf = cookie;
    return (ssize_t)size;
}

int main(void)
{
    cookie_io_functions_t x;
    x.read = ck_read;
    x.write = ck_write;
    x.seek = ck_seek;
    x.close = ck_close;
    fopencookie(NULL, NULL, x);
    return 0;
}
])], [ck_cv_libc_fopencookie=yes], [ck_cv_libc_fopencookie=no])])
if test "x${ck_cv_libc_fopencookie}" = xno ; then
    AC_CACHE_CHECK(
        [whether fopencookie works at all],
        [ck_cv_libc_fopencookie_gnu],
        [AC_LINK_IFELSE(
            [AC_LANG_SOURCE(
                [#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#endif
#include <stdio.h>

cookie_read_function_t *ck_read = (cookie_read_function_t *)foo_read;
cookie_write_function_t *ck_write = (cookie_write_function_t *)ck_read;
cookie_seek_function_t *ck_seek = (cookie_seek_function_t *)ck_read;
cookie_close_function_t *ck_close = (cookie_close_function_t *)fclose;

size_t foo_read(void *cookie, char *buf, size_t size)
{
    cookie = buf;
    buf = cookie;
    return (ssize_t)size;
}

int main(void)
{
    cookie_io_functions_t x;
    x.read = ck_read;
    x.write = ck_write;
    x.seek = ck_seek;
    x.close = ck_close;
    fopencookie(NULL, NULL, x);
    return 0;
}
])], [ck_cv_libc_fopencookie_gnu=yes], [ck_cv_libc_fopencookie_gnu=no])])

    if test "x${ck_cv_libc_fopencookie_gnu}" = xyes ; then
        AC_DEFINE([_GNU_SOURCE], [1])
        ck_cv_libc_fopencookie=yes
    fi # test with _GNU_SOURCE succeeded
fi # test without _GNU_SOURCE failed

if test "x${ck_cv_libc_fopencookie}" = xyes ; then
    AC_DEFINE(
        [HAVE_FOPENCOOKIE], [1],
        [Define to 1 if fopencookie and related functionality is fully working.])
fi])
```

I wrapped it in a macro named `ck_FUNC_FOPENCOOKIE`, so you could place it inside a standalone m4 file that gets included via `m4_include` before you call the macro. This will prevent your configure script from getting terribly cluttered, and it is easy to add and test (and remove as well).

A summary of the above code's behavior:

- **No compilable/linkable fopencookie function or types aren't what is expected:**

  - ck_cv_libc_fopencookie = no
  - ck_cv_libc_fopencookie_gnu = no
  - _GNU_SOURCE (AC_DEFINE) = undefined
  - HAVE_FOPENCOOKIE = undefined
- **fopencookie works, _GNU_SOURCE not required:**

  - ck_cv_libc_fopencookie = yes
  - ck_cv_libc_fopencookie_gnu = unset
  - _GNU_SOURCE (AC_DEFINE) = undefined
  - HAVE_FOPENCOOKIE = 1
- **fopencookie works, _GNU_SOURCE required:**

  - ck_cv_libc_fopencookie = yes
  - ck_cv_libc_fopencookie_gnu = yes
  - _GNU_SOURCE (AC_DEFINE) = 1
  - HAVE_FOPENCOOKIE = 1

As you can see, there is more to it than the `_GNU_SOURCE` definition or lack thereof. However, the case where `_GNU_SOURCE` isn't required is for cross-platform compatibility.

Basically `_GNU_SOURCE` is only enabled when required (Glibc), and you still get a definition `HAVE_FOPENCOOKIE` if the `fopencookie` stuff is usable. I used a very generic test, but you could easily edit the code to make it more appropriate.

However, the primary difference between the `AC_CHECK_FUNC` macro and the above code is the fact that I used a link test to ensure the C library contained a symbol for the `fopencookie` function. If it didn't, it would be deemed unusable, even if there was such a function on another system that resided in a different library. Since I don't know anything about the targets of your project, I can only comment on the fact that you would need to save the `LIBS` variable, set it to include a particular library depending on the target, call the `AC_LINK_IFELSE` macro, and restore the value of `LIBS` after both tests are complete. This could even be done in the main code before calling the macro above.

I suppose the simplest way to "have your cake and eat it too" would have been to determine whether glibc is detected using a `AC_PREPROC_IFELSE` call and whatever macro is unique to Glibc would be checked to determine that it is defined. If it is, then do the checks you had to ensure the version present included the function and members you need. If the checks succeeded, you'd automatically define `_GNU_SOURCE`, and everything would be great. But you sacrifice cross-platform compatibility, which is kind of the point of the GNU Autotools, and the same checks can be done without relying on Glibc being present. For all I know without researching, uClibc may have the same stuff, despite not being Glibc and not having any Glibc-specific preprocessor symbols.

Comment: I'd like to give this answer more than one upvote since it contains a lot of useful information about Autoconf in this context, but I feel that the answer I received from the Autoconf mailing list (which I posted in a separate answer, see which) should be considered the authoritative answer.

Comment: That being said, however, I don't think there's ever a case when `fopencookie` is available without defining `_GNU_SOURCE`.

Answer (score 1):

Either turn on system extensions unconditionally, or write your own `AC_DEFINE` (with template etc.).  I'd do the former.